# SQL on Server Core pitfalls

Tags: windows-server-core, sql-server-2016

We are going to try new SQL Server 2016 and we're thinking to install it on Windows Server Core. I know there are some benefits from going this way. From what I've heard, this setup is more secure and it is much easier to manage. But are there any risks or maybe limitations for the running SQL on Server Core OS? Also can you recommend a good guide on the installing procedure? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault!  This isn't really the format for the question(s) you're asking.  It's really way too broad without the ability to provide a definitive answer.  I'd suggest you (re)read the topic on acceptable questions - http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic and alternatively unacceptable questions - http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for the limitations, some of the services would be unavailable. But I doubt they are critical. Here you can learn more: https://logicalread.com/installing-sql-server-2016-on-server-core/#.WKOlJfL5MTA
Also take a look at this article that is described all the supported features and an installation process of SQL on Server Core: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx
And here it is a short step-by-step guide: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/install-sql-server-2016-on-windows-server-2016-server-core Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Core has smaller installation footprint, less binaries to patch, less services etc. Still all tech except GUI and GUI-dependent is available (Nano is somewhere limited, say with SR-IOV support). P.S. We either do a full GUI or POC Nano. Core is somewhere in the middle, and will fade out eventually. IMHO.